# JQuery, find element with comma separated items

Tags: jquery, ajax, find

I got a silly question but I really need to know the answer and I didn't find it in JQuery documentations.

I have a form which its data is sent by ajax, but I don't understand the `,` sign between 2 parts of `document.find('items1, items2')`!
What that `,` does and what it means?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $(document).find('#hdn input[type=\'hidden\'], .modal-body input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked'),
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
```

Hidden is HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="input-option20">
        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[20][]" value="64">
                <span>Mint</span> </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[20][]" value="63">
                <span>Maroon</span> </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option[20][]" value="62">
                <span>Ecru</span> </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="input-option19"> Size: <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option-19-59" name="option[19][]" value="59">
            S </label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option-19-60" name="option[19][]" value="60">
            M </label>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="option-19-61" name="option[19][]" value="61">
            L </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="hdn">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" id="product_id"       value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity"     id="input-quantity" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="unit-price" id="unit-price"       value="0" />
</div>
```

Comment: That's CSS selector for `OR`: `selector1, selector2` means `selector1` OR `selector2`. That's said, i really don't understand the use of `$(document).find(...)` instead of just `$(...)`?!

Comment: take a look to [jQuery Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: Interesting!!! Thanks a lot!